# Date Format then add 3 hours

Tags: php, date, time, timezone

How could I take something that is formatted such as `June 15, 2012 06:37PM` in the PST timezone and convert it to `06/15/12 06:37PM` but in the EST timezone (thus it will be `06/15/12 09:37PM`).

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: @sczizzo In all honesty I haven't tried. I assume after 5 minutes of googling and 10 minutes of trial and error I could come  up with the solution. I posted this to SO because someone more experienced may know it off the top of their head, or someone with more time may actually have fun problem solving it. Sometimes I use SO when I come to a programming obstacle, I post it to SO and then work on something else for an hour. Come back and I have my solution, as if I had a team of 10,000 programming partners. Sorry if this wasn't the intent of the site, but I know some of you do it too :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use PHP >= 5.2.0 you can try this solution:

```
$date = 'June 15, 2012 06:37PM';
$nDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('F d, Y h:iA' , $date, new DateTimeZone('PST'));
$nDate->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('EST'));
echo $nDate->format('m/d/y h:iA');
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using timezones you could just do:

```
$new_date = strtotime($date) + strtotime("+3 hours");
$new_date = date('m/d/y h:ia', $new_date);
```